Comic, webcomic, or manga with female lead who has a space pocket and is a beast tamer
I am looking for a manga, comic, or webcomic in which the female lead has been reborn with a special ability. She has access to a space she can enter and use to store things. Additionally, any animal she places in this space becomes tamed.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

The Weakest Tamer Began a Journey to Pick up Trash? She has a taming ability. She has a expanded space bag. But if she uses the bags to tame monsters, I didn't see it happen while skimming the early chapters.

@qazmlpok definitely not that. She doesn't use a bag to tame.

Is this "manhua". And from what I see is this apocalypse theme?
